# Dynamic Routes Settings In Ruby on Rails Like Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Current routes has been defined as:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :users do
        resources :mapps
        resources :listings
        resources :likes
        get 'followers'  => 'connections#followers'
        get 'following' => 'connections#following'
        post 'unfollow' => 'connections#unfollow'
    end
    get ':username' => 'users#public_profile'
end
```

I would like make routes like facebook:

```
   :username/:controller/:action => users/:controller/:action
```

For example, If user hit a URL as /myusername/posts/12 then request must goes to controller file inside user folder & User:Posts

I have seen many related questions but did not work with Rails 4.2.3

Comment: Facebook is a single page app (SPI app). You can make a Rails app single page by unwiring the Rails routing and wiring in a new routing pattern using Angular JS + jquery, as one example. Read here: http://www.angularonrails.com/how-to-wire-up-ruby-on-rails-and-angularjs-as-a-single-page-application-gulp-version/ .  I don't know of any simple gem-based solution, but maybe someone will answer who knows. (I am looking into making a rails app SPI as an exercise, but have not implemented. That's why this is not an answer, just ideas. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers

```
scope ':username' do
        resources :mapps
        resources :listings
        resources :likes
        get 'followers'  => 'connections#followers'
        get 'following' => 'connections#following'
        post 'unfollow' => 'connections#unfollow' 
end
```